# Why isn't the display toggling in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to do something where clicking one div would toggle the display of another div between block and none.

```
<div id="filtertop" onclick="toggleFilter()">Filter</div>
```

```
 function toggleFilter() {
      let x = document.getElementById("filter").style.display;
      if (x == "none") {
        x = "flex";
      }
      else{
        x = "none";
      }
        
    }
```

Currently, the code does nothing when I click on the div with id="filtertop"; the display should be changing to none.

Comment: No, `x` is changing to `"none"` (and then nothing else is ever done with `x`). You never assign anything back to `document.getElementById('filter').style.display`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code was already explained by @CherryDT within the comments.

Either you have to change your JS to:

```
function toggleFilter() {
  let x = document.getElementById("filter");
  if (x == "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

The smarter and more modern solution would be to use `classList.toggle('class-name')` as shown in the example below. That applies a CSS class and toggles. Therefore you do not need to use an if / else statement.

```js
function toggleFilter() {
  document.querySelector('.filter').classList.toggle('d-none');
}
```

```css
.filter {
  display: flex;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
.filter {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: red;
  grow: 1;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#filtertop {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="filtertop" onclick="toggleFilter()">Filter</div>

<div class="filter">Filter Element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean that?

```js
function toggleFilter() {
  let x = document.getElementById("filter");
  if (x.style.display == "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="filtertop" onclick="toggleFilter()">Filter</div>
<div id="filter">div with ID</div>
```

Comment: `.style` doesn’t need to be repeated; `const x = document.getElementById("filter").style;` is possible, too. Toggling a class is still better. `onclick` is still bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the point you taught me